# How to create a function that returns an observable that will emit multiple times?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I've got a function that will return an observable that will emit an enum based on what stage it is currently on. The enum basically goes like this:

```
enum ViewModelAction {
    case inputEnabled(isEnabled: Bool)
    case loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: Bool)
    case errorMessageShownIfAvailable(error: Error?)
    case loadUIData(with entity: Entity)
    case startSession(for entity: Entity)
    case endSession(for entity: Entity)
    case loadEndUIData(with entity: Entity)
}
```

Now what I want the function do is like so:

1. Function start with input params -> go to 2
2. Do:

   - Emit disable input from UI
   - Emit show loading indicator
   - Call API to create session based on input params -> API returns session data -> go to 3
3. Do:

   - If success -> go to 4
   - If error:

     - Emit enable input from UI
     - Emit hide loading indicator
     - Emit show error with the error -> Complete stream
4. Do:

   - Loop and call API to poll the entity based on the session with the status of READY:

     - If success with READY status -> Emit load UI data with entity -> go to 5
     - If success with non READY status -> loop again / back to 4
     - If error -> Emit show error with the error -> Loop again / back to 4
5. Do:

   - Call API to start session using the entity -> API returns session data -> go to 6
6. Do:

   - If success:

     - Emit enable input from UI
     - Emit hide loading indicator
     - Emit start session for entity -> Complete stream
   - If error:

     - Emit enable input from UI
     - Emit hide loading indicator
     - Emit show error with the error -> Complete stream

So in a way, for a successful run, it will emit this exact sequence:

```
Observable.merge(
    .just(ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: false)),
    .just(ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: true)),
    .just(ViewModelAction.loadUIData(with: entity)),
    .just(ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: true)),
    .just(ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: false)),
    .just(ViewModelAction.startSession(for: entity)),
    .complete()
)
```

I have actually done this, but I was thinking that it is not that clear and very complicated.

```
protocol SessionHandlerProtocol {
    func create(for userId: String) -> Observable<SessionData>
    func start(session: SessionData, entity: Entity) -> Observable<Void>
}

protocol EntityPollerProtocol {
    var entity: Observable<Entity?> { get }
    func startPolling(for session: SessionData) //Will poll and emit to entity observable
    finc stopPolling()
}

class StartSessionStrategy {
    private let sessionHandler: SessionHandlerProtocol
    private let entityPoller: EntityPollerProtocol
    init(sessionHandler: SessionHandlerProtocol,
         entityPoller: EntityPollerProtocol) {

        self.sessionHandler = sessionHandler
        self.entityPoller = entityPoller
    }

    func handleSession(with userId: String) -> Observable<ViewModelAction> {
        let initialUIObservable = 
            Observable.from(ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: false),
                            ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: true))

        let sharedCreateSession = 
            sessionHandler.create(for: userID).materialize.share()

        let createSessionError =
            sharedCreateSession
                .flatMapLatest {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .error(let error):
                        return Observable.merge(
                            .just(ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: true)),
                            .just(ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: false)),
                            .just(ViewModelAction.errorMessageShownIfAvailable(error: error)),
                            .complete()
                        )
                    default:
                        return .never()
                }

        let createSessionSuccess = 
            sharedCreateSession
                .flatMapLatest {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .next(let element):
                        return .just(element)
                    default:
                        return .never()
                }

        let sharedEntityPoller = 
            createSessionSuccess
                .do(onNext: { [weak self] in self?.entityPoller.startPolling(for: $0) })
                .withLatestFrom(entityPoller.entity) { return ($0, $1) }
                .materialize()
                .share()

        let entityPollerError =
            sharedEntityPoller
                .flatMapLatest {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .error(let error):
                        return .just(ViewModelAction.errorMessageShownIfAvailable(error: error))
                    default:
                        return .never()
                }

        let entityPollerSuccessWithReadyStatus = 
            sharedEntityPoller
                .filter { (_, entity) entity.status = .ready }
                .flatMapLatest {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .next(let element):
                        return .just(element)
                    default:
                        return .never()
                }
                .do(onNext: { [weak self] _ in self?.stopPolling() })

        let doOnEntityPollerSuccessWithReadyStatus = 
                entityPollerSuccessWithReadyStatus
                    .map { return ViewModelAction.loadUIData(with: $0.1) }

        let sharedStartSession = 
            entityPollerSuccessWithReadyStatus
                .flatMapLatest { [weak self] (session, entity) in
                    self?.sessionHandler
                        .start(session: userID, entity: entity)
                        .map { return (session, entity) }
                }.materialize.share()

        let startSessionError =
            sharedStartSession
                .flatMapLatest {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .error(let error):
                        return Observable.merge(
                            .just(ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: true)),
                            .just(ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: false)),
                            .just(ViewModelAction.errorMessageShownIfAvailable(error: error)),
                            .complete()
                        )
                    default:
                        return .never()
                }

        let startSessionSuccess = 
            sharedStartSession
                .flatMapLatest {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .next(let element):
                        return Observable.merge(
                            .just(ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: true)),
                            .just(ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: false)),
                            .just(ViewModelAction.startSession(for: element.1)),
                            .complete
                        )
                    default:
                        return .never()
                }

        return Observable.merge(
            initialUIObservable,
            createSessionError,
            entityPollerError,
            doOnEntityPollerSuccessWithReadyStatus,
            startSessionError,
            startSessionSuccess
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, the function is pretty big and not that clear. Do you have a suggestion how to refactor this into a cleaner code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a flow chart, you will end up with an imperative solution. Instead consider each side effect independently. Make each observable sequence a declaration of what causes that side effect.

The essence of your code is this (Note, I wrapped up your entity poller into a more reasonable interface. That wrapper is shown later):

```
let errors = PublishSubject<Error>()
let session = sessionHandler.create(for: userId)
    .catch { errors.onSuccess($0); return .empty() }
    .share()

let entity = session
    .flatMapLatest { [entityPoller] in
        entityPoller($0)
            .catch { errors.onSuccess($0); return .empty() }
    }
    .share()

let started = entity
    .compactMap { $0 }
    .filter { $0.status == .ready }
    .withLatestFrom(session) { ($1, $0) }
    .flatMapLatest { [sessionHandler] session, entity in
        sessionHandler.start(session: session, entity: entity)
            .catch { errors.onSuccess($0); return .empty() }
    }
    .take(1)
    .share()
```

Everything else is just notifications. I think showing the above, cleanly and without complications, is a huge simplification and will aid in other's understanding your code (including future you.)

Here is what I ended up with, including the wrapper around the poller I mentioned above:

```
class StartSessionStrategy {
    private let sessionHandler: SessionHandlerProtocol
    private let entityPoller: (SessionData) -> Observable<Entity?>

    init(sessionHandler: SessionHandlerProtocol, poller: EntityPollerProtocol) {
        self.sessionHandler = sessionHandler
        self.entityPoller = entityPolling(poller)
    }

    func handleSession(with userId: String) -> Observable<ViewModelAction> {
        // the fundamental operations as above:
        let errors = PublishSubject<Error>()
        let session = sessionHandler.create(for: userId)
            .catch { errors.onSuccess($0); return .empty() }
            .share()

        let entity = session
            .flatMapLatest { [entityPoller] in
                entityPoller($0)
                    .catch { errors.onSuccess($0); return .empty() }
            }
            .share()

        let started = entity
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .filter { $0.status == .ready }
            .withLatestFrom(session) { ($1, $0) }
            .flatMapLatest { [sessionHandler] session, entity in
                sessionHandler.start(session: session, entity: entity)
                    .catch { errors.onSuccess($0); return .empty() }
            }
            .take(1)
            .share()

        // now go through all the notifications:

        // input is disabled at start, then enabled once started or if an error occurs
        let inputEnabled = Observable.merge(
            started,
            errors.take(until: started).map(to: ())
        )
        .map(to: ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: true))
        .startWith(ViewModelAction.inputEnabled(isEnabled: false))
        .take(2)

        // show the loading indicator at start, remove it once started or if an error occurs
        let loadingIndicator = Observable.merge(
            started,
            errors.take(until: started).map(to: ())
        )
        .map(to: ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: false))
        .startWith(ViewModelAction.loadingIndicatorShown(isShown: true))
        .take(2)

        // emit the loadUIData if an entity is ready.
        let loadUIData = entity
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .filter { $0.status == .ready }
            .map { ViewModelAction.loadUIData(entity: $0) }
            .take(1)

        // emit the startSession event once the session starts.
        let startSession = started
            .withLatestFrom(entity.compactMap { $0 })
            .map { entity in ViewModelAction.startSession(entity: entity) }
            .take(until: errors)

        return Observable.merge(
            inputEnabled,
            loadingIndicator,
            errors
                .take(until: started)
                .map { ViewModelAction.errorMessageShownIfAvailable(error: $0) }, // emit an error message for all errors.
            loadUIData,
            startSession
        )
    }
}

func entityPolling(_ poller: EntityPollerProtocol) -> (SessionData) -> Observable<Entity?> {
    { session in
        Observable.create { observer in
            let disposable = poller.entity
                .subscribe(observer)
            poller.startPolling(for: session)
            return Disposables.create {
                disposable.dispose()
                poller.stopPolling()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ObserverType {
    func onSuccess(_ element: Element) -> Void {
        onNext(element)
        onCompleted()
    }
}

extension ObservableType {
    func map<T>(to: T) -> Observable<T> {
        return map { _ in to }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got to say, yours is a lot more clear than mine. So basically, instead of separating them into a different shared stream, it's better to think of them as side effects, right? And thanks again for making the entityPolling function. I didn't think of that.

Comment: In our code we have side-effects and we have logic. A side-effect either produces a value or it consumes a value. I call the former "Causes" and the latter "Effects". Values go from causes to effects, usually with some business logic in between.
So what we have is: `[Cause] -> [Logic] -> [Effect]`. Of course we can also link these cause/logic/effect chains together such that the effect of one chain is the cause of another. The key is to consider each Effect as an independent unit. What are the causes that can trigger it and what is the logic applied to the value(s) before they are fed to it.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. So basically decouple the causes and effects then?